# install php on server (iis6) when php already exists due to backup exec

Tags: php, iis-6, windows-server-2003, backupexec

I need to install or use php on a windows 2003 server that already has php 5.2.0.0 installed due (I think) to setting up symantec backup exec.  I don't want to interfere with backup exec's php.ini settings - and would rather be able to control my own configuration of php.

searching for php shows that php.exe and other php files are currently installed in 
c:\program files\symantec\backup exec\

I'm almost certain that installing the current version of php 5.2.8 to c:\php would be disastrous or calamitous in some way.

There is no PHPRC entry in the server properties > environment variables and I'm pretty sure that the php.exe location is not included in the PATH variable.   ...unless the actuall install location is different from the c:\program files\symantec\backup exec\ dir.

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm almost certain that installing the current version of php 5.2.8 to c:\php would be disastrous or calamitous in some way.

What makes you say that :) I've run separate PHP versions on the same machine side by side and not run into bother.

AFAIK the Symantec install should not conflict with your own installation, nor should the separate php.ini files conflict with each other.

[Response to comment]

First thing to note is that I have no experience of Backup Exec or what it uses PHP for. I'm guessing it uses it for its own internal stuff and doesn't spread itself over the OS. Test this by searching for php.ini and php DLLs on the file system. I'm betting it's all quite self contained. PHP searches for the config file as noted here: [PHP Site](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php) . As you note, BE hasn't set the PHPRC variable. Check it hasn't used those Registry entries either. On a different tack, has BE installed an admin site already on IIS? If so, check the IIS Web Service Extensions to make sure it hasn't already registered the PHP ISAPI dll or PHP CGI exe. IF not, I think you should be okay for your new install.

To be on the safe side, do a manual PHP install as illustrated here: [PHP Site](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.manual.php). That way, you know exactly what you have installed, and can easily remove the files again if they cause a problem. I can't imagine a problem here that would require you to reinstall BE.

Comment: Would that be true even if both backup exec AND my install of php were included in the $PATH variable? Like I said, I don't believe that backup exec modified the PATH var, but I just want to game out all possible problems. Having to reinstall Backup Exec would be a big mess at this point.

Comment: Thanks a lot James.  I'll dig back into it, and I'll read through those links later today.  I'll report back after having a chance to install, and give you credit for the answer.

Thanks for the extra thoughts and the links.

Comment: I looked through your suggestions and confirmed that BE was definitely secluded and decided to bite the bullet and do the manual install.  So far, it looks like you were right.  Thanks a lot James!